# Hiding intermediate computations in Python module

Tags: python, namespaces, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a Python file in a Jupyter notebook, `src/data.py`, that's meant to read a data file and make some outputs available.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sha256_perf = (
    pd.read_csv('data/hashbench-output.txt', sep='\t', na_filter=False)
        .query('Algorithm == "SHA256"')
)

mean_throughput = sha256_perf['Throughput (MiB/s)'].mean()
variance = sha256_perf['Error (± MiB/s)'] ** 2
total_variance = variance.sum()
row_count = sha256_perf.shape[0]
variance_of_mean = total_variance / (row_count ** 2)
error_of_mean = variance_of_mean ** 0.5

sha256_summary = pd.DataFrame(data=[[mean_throughput, error_of_mean]])
sha256_summary.columns = ['Mean Throughput (MiB/s)', 'Error (± MiB/s)']
```

Of this, the only variables I care about are the output tables -- `sha256_perf` and `sha256_summary`. However, Python has no way of knowing that, so if I `dir()` the module, I get everything:

```
>>> import src.data as data
>>> dir(data)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__',
'__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'assumptions', 'error_of_mean', 
'mean_throughput', 'np', 'pd', 'prd_scratch_2018', 'row_count', 'sha256_perf', 
'sha256_summary', 'total_variance', 'util', 'variance', 'variance_of_mean']
```

If this was Ruby or Scala, I could initialize `sha256_summary` in a block, something like:

```ruby
sha256_summary = begin
  mean_throughput = sha256_perf['Throughput (MiB/s)'].mean()
  # ... etc. ...
  df.columns = ['Mean Throughput (MiB/s)', 'Error (± MiB/s)']
  df
end
```

Even in Java (8+), I could hack something together with a `Supplier` and a lambda.

But as far as I can tell, Python doesn't have anonymous blocks or multiline lambdas. So so far, the best I've been able to come up with is putting everything in a function:

```python
def create_summary():
    mean_throughput = sha256_perf['Throughput (MiB/s)'].mean()
    # ... etc. ...
    sha256_summary.columns = ['Mean Throughput (MiB/s)', 'Error (± MiB/s)']
    return sha256_summary

sha256_summary = create_summary()
```

But this still exports the `create_summary` symbol, which I'd rather avoid:

```
>>> dir(data)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', 
'__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'assumptions', 'create_summary', 
'np', 'pd', 'prd_scratch_2018', 'sha256_perf', 'sha256_summary', 'util']
```

What's the Pythonic way to avoid polluting the global namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Right leg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49460223/364696) is good but I wanted to point out the other ways of defining the "meaningful" names in a module rather than deleting stuff after the fact.

The first option is to define `__all__` in your module. `__all__` is a sequence of strings that are part of your module's interface; if a user of your module does `from modulename import *`, and `__all__` is defined, they only pull the names in `__all__`. So in your case, you'd just add:

```
__all__ = ['sha256_perf', 'sha256_summary']
```

near the top of your module (position doesn't matter, but by convention it's placed near the top, typically just after the imports). Many introspection tools use this information as well to limit what parts of the module are included in the output (e.g. `help(modulename)` on a module with `__all__` excludes the classes and functions not included in `__all__`).

Alternatively, you can avoid `__all__`, and just make sure all non-public parts of the module are named with a leading underscore; when `__all__` is not defined, the "virtual" `__all__` behavior is to include names without leading underscores, and omit names with leading underscores. So if all names besides the two you care about are underscore prefixed (including imported module names, e.g. `import numpy as _np`, `import pandas as _pd`), then they'll be omitted when `from modulename import *` is used, and typically omitted from `help()` output and the like.

No, it doesn't change the set of names seen by `dir` (though tab completion facilities will frequently omit names that begin with underscores), but it's the official way to declare the names that are considered part of your public API.

Answer (score 3):

You're not polluting the global namespace, because the variables you don't care about are still inside the `data` namespace, that is, they are attributes of the `data` module.

Furthermore, you cannot just *hide* a module attribute: if `create_summary` is defined in the module, then `import data` will bring `data` in, along with its `create_summary` attribute.
However, you can delete it, by calling `del create_summary` at the end of `data.py`.
This way, it won't appear in `dir(data)`.

Here is a short example:

```
# data.py
module_level_attribute = None                                              

def init():                                                                 
    global module_level_attribute                                           
    module_level_attribute = 2                                              

init()                                                                      
del init
```

Then, `module_level_attribute` will appear in `dir(data)`, but not `init`:

```
>>> import data
>>> dir(data)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__',
 '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'module_level_attribute']
```

Still, using the `del` statement is not really satisfying.

The approach I would prefer, would be to make all the processing in a function, and to provide only the interesting variables as module-level attributes, just like you did.
It's okay, because it does not actually pollute the global namespace.
To take it further, you could name that initialization function with a leading underscore, to indicate that it's "private", which would hide it from the `help` function, although it would still appear in `dir(data)`.

However, if you really do want to import only what you need, then you should use the `from ... import` syntax.
This time, the imported variable will be brought into the global namespace, so you will lose the explicitness of `data.sha256_perf`.
On the other hand, you won't have anything else from the `data` module.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the block-initialization behavior, simply re-use the name of the variable as the function name.

```
def sha256_summary():
    mean_throughput = sha256_perf['Throughput (MiB/s)'].mean()
    # ... etc. ...
    sha256_summary.columns = ['Mean Throughput (MiB/s)', 'Error (± MiB/s)']
    return sha256_summary

sha256_summary = sha256_summary()
```

Yes, this is allowed in Python. Functions are just another kind of value. This will set a function named `sha256_summary` in the module's globals, then the following assignment statement will overwrite that name with its return value.

Python's decorators use this pattern all the time. They typically return a wrapped function replacement, but this is actually not required. Decorators can return any value, and this value replaces the function's name in the local scope. So we could implement the above pattern as a decorator.

```
def begin(f):
    return f()
```

Then if you decorate that function like so,

```
@begin
def sha256_summary():
    mean_throughput = sha256_perf['Throughput (MiB/s)'].mean()
    # ... etc. ...
    sha256_summary.columns = ['Mean Throughput (MiB/s)', 'Error (± MiB/s)']
    return sha256_summary
```

You again get the return value in `sha256_summary`, without repeating the name. Of course, `begin` is now a global in the module. Delete it afterwards if you must, but it is normal in Python for modules to contain more than their intended exports.

Answer (score 0):

Do everything in a function, call that function, then delete the function. Declare anything you want to keep as `global`.

```
def _private():
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    global sha256_perf
    sha256_perf = (
        pd.read_csv('data/hashbench-output.txt', sep='\t', na_filter=False)
            .query('Algorithm == "SHA256"')
    )

    mean_throughput = sha256_perf['Throughput (MiB/s)'].mean()
    variance = sha256_perf['Error (± MiB/s)'] ** 2
    total_variance = variance.sum()
    row_count = sha256_perf.shape[0]
    variance_of_mean = total_variance / (row_count ** 2)
    error_of_mean = variance_of_mean ** 0.5

    global sha_256_summary
    sha256_summary = pd.DataFrame(data=[[mean_throughput, error_of_mean]])
    sha256_summary.columns = ['Mean Throughput (MiB/s)', 'Error (± MiB/s)']

_private()
del _private
```

This approach is not particularly Pythonic, but you see this kind of thing all the time in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use a package instead of a module to control the exports. A "package" just means that you put your module file in a directory, and then import just the names you want using a special Python file called `__init__.py`. So instead of `src/data.py`, you have `src/data/data.py` and `src/data/__init__.py`. Your `data.py` is just like before, and in the `__init__.py`, you have

```
from .data import sha256_perf, sha256_summary
```

That's it. Now when you `import data` you get the package, and it has `sha256_perf` and `sha256_summary` in its dir, but not all the other junk in `data.py`. (It does include the `data` module itself, and the normal dunder names that come with every Python module.)